# The Stark-Lo Surdo effect

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, laser, laser-cavity

What does the [Stark-Lo Surdo effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stark_effect) consist of in the interaction of the electromagnetic field and the active medium in a laser? I thank those who want to give a clear and concise answer.
In my student notes from the seventies, I found the topic I was looking for, the calculation for which I attach. But what happens in practice (since I don't have an optics laboratory available)?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]